# Create custom section tree from .sitemap file

Tags: xml, umbraco

I have an application that I wish to integrate in into umbraco. However, I have done the integration part but I am struggling in adding the tree of that application to the new section, I have a **.sitemap** file and want umbraco to read it and display the tree.

Any suggestions!

Comment: I have tried and failed using he cms import tool. Interested in the answer

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you need Matt Brailsfords' sitemap app tree package: [which can be found here in the Umbraco package repository](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/sitemapapptree) instructions for setup and use are on the repo page, but it should do what you're after!

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I know that blog article and I watched the video a few times before... Unfortunately, that article is now outdated and I am integrating my MVC code into umbraco 5. I guess I just need some vacation, I believe it is not that complicated, I made similar classes before but now couldn't remake it again, my head is over flooded with unwanted algorithms :(